# Segmentation fault error upon calling pip in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip

When I try to execute some command using `pip` or `pip3` in a (freshly created) virtualenv, I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.  For example,

```
$ pip --version
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But everything works as expected outside of the virtualenv.

I am using Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04, where `virtualenv` was installed via `pip install virtualenv`.  I created the virtualenv using `virtualenv --no-site-packages -p python3.7 stylify_venv`.

Comment: Very strange.  Obviously an environment issue as that works fine for me and I assume for almost everyone else.  Have you done other things in this same vitualenv that work ok?  Is there anything that you can think of that is special about this particular virtualenv?  What happens if you try creating a brand new virtualenv...does it happen immediately there too?

Comment: @Steve This virtualenv is freshly created.  Yes, I tried creating a new virtualenv, with the same result.  The virtualenv was created using `virtualenv --no-site-packages -p python3.7 my_env`.  Opening a python shell in the same terminal works just fine.  I'll edit my question with this relevant info.

Comment: Yikes.  No idea.  Is this the first time you've done this sort of thing in this environment, or did it start happening at some point?  If the latter, I assume you don't know of anything you did that would have initiated the behavior. I assume it's python that's crashing. Or is pip its own binary? - The only thing I can think to do is reinstall stuff...pip and then python.

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 a couple days ago, and this is the first virtualenv I've created on this device.  Hm, yeah re-installing may be next on the list.

Comment: wow...fresh env...particularly harsh :(

Comment: With the information you gave, I am afraid SO won't be able to help you. Maybe check if your RAM is full. I think you should raise an issue on the proper Github repo if you think this is an issue.

Comment: $sudo pip --version